# Dynamically add Scripts inside a div using Jquery

Tags: jquery

How can I add script tags inside a div using jquery .

I want it like

```
<div id="scriptContainer" >
       <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="script2.js"></script>
</div>
```

I used it with jquery appendTo but it does not work.Could you please help me

Comment: script add in head not in div

Comment: Post your jquery code!!!

Comment: What's the reason for adding a script to a DIV and not in your header or before your closing `<body />` tag?

Comment: If you're trying to `document.write()` content into that div from these scripts, you cannot do it after the document has been loaded like this.  The scripts will have to be modified to append content to that div.

Answer (score 1):

## Try using `jQuery.getScript()`:-

```
$.getScript("script.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
  console.log( data ); // Data returned
  console.log( textStatus ); // Success
  console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
  console.log( "Load was performed." );
});
```

<kbd>[Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)</kbd>

Comment: @Johnsmith Does this answer your query>

Answer (score 0):

You can create it as an object and then append it.

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "script.js";
$("#scriptContainer").append(script);
```