# Error when trying append script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I trying to append scripts in client side: 
example :

```
var script = '<script type="text/javascript">document.write(\'<script type="text/javascript" src=""><\\/script>\');</script> '

$('body').html(script );
```

getting error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAttribute' of null

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var scriptlog  =document.createElement('script');
scriptlog.type ='text/javascript';
scriptlog.src  =url;
$('body').append( script );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
    script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    script_tag.setAttribute("src",
        "your js url");
```

**By JAVASCRIPT**

```
// Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
(document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0] || document.documentElement).insertBefore(script_tag);
```

**By JQUERY**

```
$("head").append(script_tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Dynamically add Scripts inside HTML element -

```
var script = document.createElement( "script" );
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "script.js";
$("body").append(script);
```

[Refrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20235408/dynamically-add-scripts-inside-a-div-using-jquery/20236002)

Answer (score 0):

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'a.js';
document.head.appendChild(script)
```